# Javascript return false preventdefault onclick addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events

First of all Hello to everyone, and sorry for my English.
I would still take advantage of the expertise and availability of this community.
Although i have read many posts, my ignorance does not allow me to understand a fundamental concept.
My question is:why with onclick we can use both preventDefault an return true and with addEventListener we can use only preventDefault?
Any suggestion or example will be read with pleasure, thank you all.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
        document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e){
            return false;
            e.preventDefault()
        }
        document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
        });
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init,false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href = "http://stackoverflow.com/" id = "a">stackoverflow.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“why with onclick we can use both preventDefault an return [false] and with addEventListener we can use only preventDefault?”_ – simply because that’s _how it works_ … `addEventListener` is a more “sophisticated” way of binding event handlers, and in that model it was specified that preventing the default action of the event should be done using a dedicated method. `return false` when using onclick however is just a “relict” of the old event handling model, which originally was even applied using `onclick` _attributes_ in the HTML code itself.

Comment: @CBroe:thank you, your the answer is clear and helpful.